# What do GDIR, GREG, VDIR, VREG mean in lsof output

Tags: filesystems, lsof

The `lsof` manpage says the following about the `TYPE` column.

> TYPE       is the type of the node associated with the file - e.g., GDIR, GREG, VDIR, VREG, etc.

Can someone please explain (or point me to a link which explains) what these mean. I have tried googling on these but all the links take me to the lsof man page only.

If you find a link, do tell me how you googled it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Types starting with *V* are *virtual* types. That is, there is no corresponding *inode* on any physical disk but only a *vnode* in a virtual filesystem (like */proc*). It seems those types only belong to BSD-like systems (AIX, Darwin, FreeBSD, HPUX, Sun etc.) and won't occur on a Linux system. As with the non-virtual types, *DIR* stands for directory and *REG* for a regular file.

I couldn't find the meaning of *GDIR* and *GREG* as they even don't appear in the lsof source code. But I guess they just stand for the non-virtual (*generic*?) directories and files.